# "How much certain are you?"

Tags: questions

Is it right to use "How much certain are you?" instead of "How certain are you?", in order to emphasize that I want a quasi-quantitative answer?

Comment: No, this would be outlandish ungrammatical rather than quirky ungrammatical. "On a scale of 1 to 10, ...?"

Comment: Or "what level of certainly have you?" (probably "do you have?" for AmE speakers)

Comment: How certain are you ? would fit your context.

Comment: Please write answers as answers.

Comment: It's something that might be said by a poorly-educated person, but not "proper" English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to ask, "How certain are you?"

The response might be "I am very certain", "I am 100 percent certain", "I am not certain at all".

But never "I am much certain".